# VBA: Export Access to Excel -> Select All Cells - > format Table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I apologize for the title in advance. What I want to do is export Microsoft access data to an Excel spreadsheet, select all the Cells and format it as a table.

Problem: The data in the excel spreadsheet is not being formatted in a table as specified with the last 5 lines of code.

code:

```
Private Sub button3_Click()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range

Dim XL As Object
Dim Page As Object
Dim xlrngCell As Object
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim intF As Integer


On Error Resume Next
Set XL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If XL Is Nothing Then
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    If XL Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find Excel!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    XL.Visible = True
    XL.UserControl = True
End If

Set xlrngCell = XL.Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
Set rs = Me.subformMain.Form.RecordsetClone
For intF = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    xlrngCell(, intF + 1) = rs.Fields(intF).Name
Next intF
rs.MoveFirst
xlrngCell.Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset rs

xlrngCell.Worksheet.Parent.Saved = True
Set Page = XL.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I1")
Page.Font.Bold = True
Page.Font.Size = 16
xlrngCell.Worksheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleDark10"
xlrngCell.Worksheet.Parent.Saved = True
XL.Work

End Sub
```

The last 5 lines of code are what should be selecting all the placed data and then selecting all of the cells and formatting them. Any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I understand that I should modularize this code into separate functions and call them as methods.

Comment: Your post makes no mention of what the problem is... remove or comment-out `On Error Resume Next` and re-run it. Are you getting any error? Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is silently failing, `On Error Resume Next` is preventing you from knowing what the problem is. **Never** use `On Error Resume Next` to shove errors under the carpet like this.

Assuming the Excel type library isn't referenced (you wouldn't be late-binding then, would you?), `Range` is likely an undefined identifier. Assuming `Option Explicit` isn't specified (if it were, the code wouldn't even compile/run), these unqualified `Range` identifiers are being "declared" on-the-spot like any other typo, as an unassigned `Variant/Empty` variable that can't possibly be an object to make member calls against.

So I'm going to wager that the *actual* error you're getting is "Object Required", on this line:

```
Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
```

You know what the `Worksheet` is supposed to be:

```
Set Page = XL.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I1")
```

Declare a variable for it:

```
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = XL.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Now use that `Worksheet` object (I'd declare it well above that, and use it everywhere that sheet needs to be referenced) to qualify these `Range` calls:

```
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
```

...which can be simplified to:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
```

...except `xlLastCell` is also an identifier that doesn't exist.

In the Excel type library, the correct identifier is `xlCellTypeLastCell` - but since you're not referencing that library, VBA couldn't know what that stands for either.

`xlCellTypeLastCell` is defined in an enum, with a value of `11`.

So you could declare it like this:

```
Const xlCellTypeLastCell = 11
```

And then use it in your code:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
```

---

Edit - I missed these two:

> ```
> Dim tbl As ListObject
> Dim rng As Range
> ```

If you *are* referencing the Excel type library, then you're making your life much harder than it needs to be by declaring everything Excel `As Object`. Use the types if you have them!

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I completely overlooked the on error part, thanks for the heads up. I also forgot to reference the excel spreadsheet with its object, which ultimately made the code not work. Thanks again, i'll clean this code up for sure now.